# How to determine the name of the test script in py.test?

Tags: python, pytest

I am running a small test py.test script, and I want to determine the name of the test script being used.

The current script is run as

```
pytest selenium/test_morph_viz.py  -s
```

but later it is supposed to be run without the argument. Part of the output of the run is as follows:

```
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.3.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /home/adietz/Projects/Invest/bsp-usecase-tests, inifile:
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                        

selenium/test_morph_viz.py E
```

Within the code I define a `setup` method in which I want to get the name of the test script, i.e.

```
selenium/test_morph_viz.py
```

How to do that?

I tried to use `inspect` or `os.path.basename`, but this only returns the path of a script in which I define other things. So how to get the name of the script currently run in py.test?

Comment: Have you tried `sys.argv`?

Comment: I think `os.path.basename(__file__)` should do the thing

Comment: sys.argv always differ if we give different pytest options?
Like `python3 -m pytest -s -v <script_name>`

Answer (score -1):

Found the correct answer by chance:

```
self.__module__
```

That gives you the `module` currently used.

Comment: what is self? Can you please elaborate?